# ActiveRecord - How to use JOINS, GROUP and SELECT only certain columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, join, activerecord, group-by

If I run following query,

```
  @top_companies               = Shipment.joins(:company)
                                        .where('...')
                                        .group('companie.name')
                                        .order('count_all DESC').limit(10).count
```

the output is in the **company name => count of shipments** format:

```
"Company name"=>12, ...}
```

But I would need to fetch also other columns from the `companies` table, like the `id` and so on, so I tried:

```
  @top_companies               = Shipment.joins(:company)
                                        .select('shipments.*, companies.id, companies.name, companies.name_slug')
                                        .where('...')
                                        .group('companie.name')
                                        .order('count_all DESC').limit(10).count
```

But the output remains the same - why is that? How to add another columns to the output hash?

Comment: The hash formatted output looks you have a .count at the trail of the chain.

Comment: Yes, it is there... when I copied the block of code, I missed it, will modify the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add the `Companies` columns to `group` statement:

```
  @top_companies = Shipment.joins(:company)
                     .where('...')
                     .group('companies.id, companies.name, companies.name_slug')
                     .order(count_all: :desc).limit(10).count
```

And since you are grouping `Shipments`, if you wish to include columns from it, you need to tell SQL how you'd wish the data to be aggregated:

```
@top_companies = Shipment.joins(:company)
                   .where('...')
                   .select('AVG(shipments.delivered_in), COUNT(*), companies.id, companies.name, companies.name_slug')
                   .group('companies.id, companies.name, companies.name_slug')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the name and name_slug accordingly on the `Company` object like this:

```
@top_companies = Shipment.joins(:company)
                .select('count(*) as shipments_count, companies.id as company_id, companies.name as company_name, companies.name_slug as company_name_slug')
                .where('...')
                .group('companie.name')
                .order('count_all DESC').limit(10)

@top_companies.map(&:shipments_count)
# this will return the shipment count 

@top_companies.map(&:company_name_slug)
# this will return the company name slug corresponding to each group of shipment by company name
```

You now need to just use `@top_companies.map` and can write any logic inside `map` to get the desired output.

Answer (score -2):

try to use pluck instead of select.

```
Client.where(active: true).pluck(:id)
# SELECT id FROM clients WHERE active = 1
# => [1, 2, 3]

Client.distinct.pluck(:role)
# SELECT DISTINCT role FROM clients
# => ['admin', 'member', 'guest']

Client.pluck(:id, :name)
# SELECT clients.id, clients.name FROM clients
# => [[1, 'David'], [2, 'Jeremy'], [3, 'Jose']]
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck